# How to handle FB Login revocation or expiry in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

The official [Facebook Developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) does not mention how to handle the case for FB login access token expiry case or the case when the user revokes access to the app via FB settings.

I have a demo android app built using the official documentation, but when I revoke access to the app via Facebook settings, my app continues to work. The SDK does not automatically log me out.

Comment: Then you need to go to that FB account, security, session and remove your device.